# "Type Mismatch" Error with FileSystemObject.GetFile

Tags: vbscript, filesystemobject

This script creates a text file with a randomly generated name. I want its attribute to be Hidden System, so I applied it with `File.Attributes`.

Anyway, while running this script, text file gets created, but when it comes to applying its attributes, it throws the following error:

> Type Mismatch: 'GetFile' (Line: 7)

Here is the code:

```
Dim FSO, TList, WshShell

Set FSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set TList = FSO.GetFolder(WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%LOCALAPPDATA%") + "/Temp").CreateTextFile(FSO.GetTempName)
FSO.GetFile(TList).Attributes = 22
```

I can't think what is causing the problem because `TList` is set using the Function `CreateTextFile`. As I think, the function `CreateTextFile` does not return `Scripting.File`, it might be `TextStream` or something. Am I correct?

What is causing this error here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CreateTextFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9b5c0c(v=vs.84).aspx) method returns a [TextStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/312a5kbt(v=vs.84).aspx) object.  The error occurs because [GetFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sheydkke(v=vs.84).aspx) expects a string as an input parameter.  A TextStream can't set a file's attributes, so building a string pathname is one way to set a new file's attributes:

```
Dim FSO, WshShell, TempFolder, TempFilename

Const HiddenAttribute = 2

Set FSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

TempFolder = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%LOCALAPPDATA%") + "\Temp"

If Not FSO.FolderExists(TempFolder) Then
  FSO.CreateFolder(TempFolder)
End If

TempFilename = TempFolder + "\" + FSO.GetTempName

CreateNewFile(TempFilename)
FSO.GetFile(TempFilename).Attributes = HiddenAttribute

Sub CreateNewFile(filename)
  Dim TS
  Set TS = FSO.CreateTextFile(filename, True)
  TS.Close
End Sub
```